# How can we stop Tomcat running as a service from another Windows service?

Tags: java, windows, service, tomcat6

In our project, we are installing Tomcat as a service (say service A) and we are starting this service A from another installed Windows service (say service B). The question is (as we are successfully starting), can we stop service A on stopping service B?

Comment: You can stop one service from another, but not from within the service's control handler.  (I'm not sure what that translates to in Java terms.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston Can you provide some example or a tutorial ?

Comment: Huh?  You just call ControlService(), same as stopping a service from any other application.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Sorry , not clear to me.